# Detect Disconnect plugin from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, detect, disconnect

A [disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disconnect/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo) plugin in chrome is blocking social network widgets. And it's good. But it makes the page look odd for the visitor. Is there a way one could detect a failed social network plugin loading in javascript so it would be possible to hide the block altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
dependencyAvailabilityCheckInterval = setInterval(doDependenciesExist, 500);

function doDependenciesExist()
{
    if(typeof FB !== 'undefined')
        return;

    alert("Looks like Facebook ist blocked!");
    // do rearranging or hiding of content
}
```

You could extend/replace typeof(FB) by any other js library you might need for your website or service.

Comment: We did exactly that back then. Thank you!